# Hashing passwords in PHP

Tags: php, security

When hashing a password, I understand it is best not to use functions such as SHA1 or MD5.

This function is working fine and I want to know if it can be improved to increase site security.

```
class safePassword
{
    public static function makeSafe($password)
    {
        $salt = "mySalt";
        $hash = hash("sha256", $salt.".".$password);
        return $hash;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are like a zillion resources on this on Security.SE; have you spent 15 minutes reading through them?  e.g., http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/971.

Comment: A fixed salt is no salt.

Comment: learn and use PHP's  crypt() function

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel?  Just use: http://php.net/password_hash and http://php.net/password_verify.  (In case you don't have PHP 5.5+: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: @RocketHazmat Those two functions may be simple wrappers around `crypt`, but they certainly do protect against the most obvious mistakes one could make in calling `crypt` directly. As for the compatibility library, I am shocked by the way the `password_verify` function compares two strings. Is it really that complicated to compare two strings in php?

Comment: @kasperd, that's a constant-time string comparison, which looks about the same in every language I've used. It's needed to avoid timing attacks. However, AFAIK even those wrappers let bcrypt truncate the password to 72 characters?

Comment: @otus Every language I have used has provided a builtin string comparison function such that you wouldn't need to implement it from scratch.

Comment: @kasperd, the problem is that the builtin string comparison is usually not constant time, potentially leaking the matching prefix length through timing.

Comment: @otus That sounds very theoretical. Even if the adversary could reliably determine the exact length of the matching prefix, what could that be used for? We are talking about a comparison between two hashes neither of which is known to the adversary. The risk has to be weighed against the increasing risk of introducing bugs as the amount of code increases.

Comment: @kasperd, if the attacker knows the salt, it's a comparison between a known and an unknown hash, allowing the attacker to narrow down the possibilities much faster than knowing just success/failure. Yes, keeping the salt secret is better, but it's a general purpose library, so that cannot be assumed.

Comment: @otus Salt and hash are stored together as a single string. To all code outside of the library that is an opaque value with no structure. As such any realistic leak will either leak both the salt and the hash or neither. So ultimately this boils down to cover only the case where a weak random number source was used to generate the salt in the first place. Additionally in order to exploit it, an attacker would have to reliably measure a tiny variation in the timing of a long running hashing operation.

Comment: @otus What we are talking about here is an attacker having to reliably tell the difference in timing between two string compares where the length of the matching prefix differs by a single character. And the attacker has to detect this from measurements covering not just the string compare, but rather the timing of a bcrypt hash followed by a string compare. The comparison of a single character takes a very short duration compared to computing a bcrypt hash. I still estimate a higher probability that the additional code introduced a bug than the probability of such an attack succeeding.

Comment: @kasperd, the library allows salts to be generated non-randomly. With e.g. an email address as salt the attacker could know it without knowing the hash. Complex timing attacks have succeeded before in other situations. Again, as a general purpose library,it should help protect the passwords whatever choices the application programmer makes.

Comment: @otus I agree there is a risk if you have legacy passwords with a salt chosen in an incorrect way. It is still a tiny risk though. The option to pass a salt has been deprecated because it is so easy to use that option incorrectly and there is rarely any need to use it. A safer way for the library to generate the salt would actually be to not just use of of the supported random sources but instead use all of those available including a value passed by the caller. All of them could then be concatenated and hashed in order to use the resulting hash as salt.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I understand it is best not to use functions such as SHA1 or MD5.

That is true. But sha256 is not that much better.

**Problem: simple sha256**

There are basically two problems with your approach:

- you don't use a user-based salt, only a site-based salt (also called a [pepper](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41754/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-pepper)).
- you only use simple sha256, which is [way too fast](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90064/how-secure-are-sha256-salt-hashes-for-password-storage).

These are serious issues.

The main problem with missing user-based salts is that an attacker only needs to hash each password once and can then compare it to the hashes of all users, instead of needing to hash the password with each salt. This speeds up cracking considerably.

The problem with the second point should be obvious. Hardware has become quite powerful over the years, and simple hashing just doesn't hold up anymore (and hasn't for quite a while). Here for example is a benchmark of [3090.3 Million guesses per second](http://thepasswordproject.com/oclhashcat_benchmarking) on a pretty standard PC.

If your database is ever leaked - for example because of a Code Execution or SQL Injection vulnerability - it will be quite easy for an attacker to crack a good percentage of your users passwords.

**Solution: Bcrypt**

What you want to use is [bcrpyt](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). With PHP, this can be done via `password_hash` (which is also the first result when googling "php hash password").

Example:

```
// hash
$hash = password_hash("password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

echo $hash;

// check
echo "<br>" . password_verify("password", $hash);
```

User-based salts are managed automatically for you, and it uses multiple rounds of hashing, slowing the process down, and thus increasing the resources an attacker needs to crack your hashes.

You can still use a [pepper with bcrypt](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/21263/how-to-apply-a-pepper-correctly-to-bcrypt) if you want to.

For more information about [password hashing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) in general see here.

**Misc**

- `makeSafe` is not a good function name. Make safe how? `hash` would be more accurate.

Comment: In regards to "pepper", it is better to encrypt the hash using AES and your pepper would be your secret key.

Comment: @Petah, that allows an attacker who knows the salt to precompute hashes for password guesses. Using the pepper as input in the first step avoids that.

Comment: @otus I have a hard time coming up with a realistic scenario where that'd matter. Encryption at the end has at least two advantages, you can easily change the key by re-encrypting the hashes and you could delegate encryption (but not the expensive hashing) to a HSM that only allows encryption but not decryption or key extraction.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, a scenario where it would apply would be quite convoluted (specific target individual, salt known before hand, short window of opportunity after compromise of the hash). It's of course possible to combine both if you want.

Comment: @otus not sure what you mean here. I was talking about pepper, not salt.

Comment: @Petah, if you store E(pepper, H(pass, salt)), an attacker knowing the salt can calculate guesses H(pass, salt), doing the slow work of password hashing ahead of time. Then when they compromise the hashes and the pepper, they would be able to quickly check if any of their guesses matched. Realistic? Not sure, but including the pepper in the hash avoids it.

Comment: @otus Easy fix, rotate your encryption keys. Anyway your case assumes the attacker already has access to both the file system and the database, so game over anyway.

Comment: @Petah, If you assume access to the file system and database is game over you might as well use plaintext or simply encrypted passwords. That is precisely the situation that strong password storage is meant to protect against. (Encryption key rotation does nothing to prevent cracking the already stolen hashes.)

Comment: @otus but with that access you can intercept login attempts anyway. Nothing to crack if the users are giving you their passwords. Anyway, in your case of why not encrypt the hmac of the hash (salting, peppering, with a herb crust)?

Comment: @Petah, read only access is common, e.g. due to some SQL escaping bug, which does not allow interception. HMAC would not add anything, you can still do the slow work in advance... But I think I've spammed the comments enough.

Answer (score 8):

There's two sides to this review:

Security & Style.

---

### Style:

- Directly return `$hash` instead of assigning it.
- The string concatenation can be improved

into:

```
public static function makeSafe($password)
{
    $salt = "mySalt";
    return hash("sha256", "{$salt}.{$password}");
}
```

---

### Security:

When using a fixed salt, if they managed to break the compilation of the code and retrieve the plaintext salt, it would render the encrypted password down to a matching of common hashes.

Use a different salt for each user (make a random integer, more than 10 digits even), and store the salt beside the password inside the database.

Comment: This isn't necessarily improving the concatenation. If anything, `"{$salt}.{$password}"` is slightly slower than `$salt.".".$password` because it has to parse the string, extract the curly braced entries, substitute and rebuild.

Comment: How about "Don't use SHA, at all, for password hashing"....